# Limit of a double sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $A<B$ and $(a_{n,m})_{n,m\geq 1}\subset \mathbb{R}$ a double sequence satisfying:

(1) For any fixed $m\geq 1$, the sequence $(a_{m,n})_{n\geq 1}$ is strictly increasing and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{m,n}=B$

(2) For any fixed $n\geq 1$, the sequence $(a_{m,n})_{m\geq 1}$ is strictly decreasing and $\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}a_{m,n}=A$

Then, it is true that there is $k\geq 0$ such that

$\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} a_{m,m+k}=\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} a_{m,m+k+1}\neq A,B$

or

$\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} a_{m+k,m}=\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} a_{m+k+1,m}\neq A,B$ ?

Thanks in advances for you comments.

Comment: Hint: Try to find a specific example $a_{n,m}$ with $B \neq A$, or several such examples, and test them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $A < B$ and any real number $c > 0$ the double sequence 
$$
 a_{m,n} = \frac{Bm + cAn}{m + cn} 
$$
satisfies the hypotheses, but
$$
 \lim_{m\to \infty} a_{m,m} = \frac{B+cA}{1+c}
$$
can take any value in $(A, B)$.

Counter-examples to your updated question are
$$
 b_{m,n} = \frac{Be^m + An}{e^m + n} \, , \quad  c_{m,n} = \frac{Bm + Ae^n}{m + e^n}
$$
where
$$
 \lim_{m\to\infty} b_{m+k,m+l} = B  \, , \quad \lim_{m\to\infty} c_{m+k,m+l} = A
$$
for all $k, l \ge 0$.

Comment: Dear Martin R, many thanks for your example. I feel that I have not posed the problem correctly...I edit the statenment.

Comment: @user123043: Well, that is quite a different question now.

Comment: Yes, is different...From your example, it is clear that there is some sequences with this property. Again, a lot of thanks.

Comment: @user123043: The answer is still “no” – take $a_{m,n} = \frac{e^m}{e^m + n}$ as an example.

Comment: Thanks @Martin R! That is a nice example!  :)

Comment: @user123043: Does this answer your question now?

Comment: Yes, this your answer solves the question. Thanks!!

Comment: @user123043: You are welcome! You might consider to *accept* the answer if it helped.

Comment: Done! ;)  -.........................................